# Stored procedure fails to execute when calling multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to find how a stored procedure is being called.

My problem is when deleting a record from the application, it calls a stored procedure and it works fine for single record. While selecting multiple records at the same time, the program throws an error saying invalid syntax near '@'. I'm trying to find if I need to rewrite the stored procedure or if it is the application that can't recognize the variable declared in the SP.

SP Code:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[storedprocedure] 

@Variable int 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    --DML Statement--

END
```

I tried to include declaring the variable within the block but it fails to execute saying that it can't find the variable. The way it's written works for a single record. I need it to work for multiple records at the same time.

Comment: You can't assign more than 1 int value to your @variable.

Answer (score 2):

> while selecting multiple records at the same time, the program throws
>   an error

That's probably cause you have defined a scalar variable saying `@Variable int` and thus if you select multiple records and try to delete them, your scalar variable won't be able to hold them up. Probably you should consider using a `Table Type variable` or `Temporary Table` instead.

Comment: thanks! how can i use a temp table in this context? can you give me an example?